# Is $\;\frac{\ln(x+1)}x\;$ uniformly continuous in $\;[0,\infty)\;$?

Tags: calculus, uniform-continuity

I have this problem: is the function

$$f(x)=\frac{\ln(x+1)}x$$

uniformly continuous in $\;[0,\infty)\;$ ?

First, I think I could say that zero is not even in domain of function, but I can show it is a movable right discontinuity since $\;f(x)\to 1\;$ when $\;x\to 0^+\;$ , so I suppose we can have the function defined in there (is htis true?)

Now, for the uniform continuity: is possible to show that

$$f'(x)=\frac{ x-(x+1)\ln(x+1)}{x^2(x+1)}<0\;\;in\;\; [0,1]\;$$

and the function decreases in monotonically, and we also have that using LHospital

$$f'(x)\xrightarrow[x\to 0^+]{}-\frac12$$

$$f'(x)\xrightarrow[x\to \infty]{}0$$

So I think first derivative is bounded and then I get uniformly continuity.

Is the above right? Anything to say about this I'll thank very much

Comment: Show that $|f'|$ is bounded by ${ 1 \over 2}$. Then the mean value theorem shows that $f$ is globally Lipschitz, hence uniformly continuous.

Comment: Thank you @copper.hat . But if $\;f'<0\;$ and with the above two limits of derivative limits, isn't enough to show $\;|f'|\;$ is bounded?

Comment: It is, I'm not sure why I mentioned the ${1 \over 2}$.

Comment: @copper.hat If you want you can add that as answer (perhaps is needed to write more, I don't know). I will vote up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$f'(x) = {x - (x+1)\log(x+1) \over x^2(x+1)}$. It is clear that $f'(x) \to 0$ as $ x \to \infty$. Using L'Hôpital we have $f'(x) \to - {1 \over 2}$ as $x \downarrow 0$. Since $f'$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$, we see that $f'$ is bounded, that is $|f'(x)| \le M$ for some $M$.

Then the mean value theorem gives
$|f(x)-f(y)| = |f'(\xi)| |x-y| \le M |x-y|$, and so  $f$ is Lipschitz continuous.

In particular, given $\epsilon>0$, if $|x-y|< {1 \over M}\epsilon$, then
$|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$.